# Function not being called from the main JS function called using onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a new web-developer. I have a button in the HTML page modal. Onclick event is captured using getElementById. And then, I am trying to call the validation function signinVals(). The control comes upto this function but this function is not getting invoked. "usrname" is the input element in this modal.

Can someone help?

```js
document.getElementById("loginBtn").onclick = function () {
    signinVals();
}

//all sign in validations
function signinVals() {
    validateEmail();

    if (validateEmail()) {
        validatePassword();
    }
}

// validate email 
function validateEmail() {
    var uemail = document.signinformid.usrname.value;
    alert(uemail.value);
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (uemail.value.match(mailformat)) {
        return true;
        alert("Sign in: Corect email.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Sign in: Invalid email entered. Please recheck.");
        uemail.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form" name="signinformid">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usrname" class="sr-only"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter user name (email id)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="psw" class="sr-only"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
                        </div>
<!--                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="signinVals(usrname,psw)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" ></span> Login</button>-->
                        <button type="submit" id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: what is `document.signinformid.usrname`?

Comment: Just to clarify - onclick is getting invoked (alert works just above signinVals(). But it's not calling the function signonVals.

Comment: how you write `document.signinformid.usrname` in html?

Comment: @ewwink: I just added a code snippet of HTML also. It is used within the form as an input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right maybe this help you. Of course jQuery because its nice to write with

```
  $('#loginBtn').click(function(){
  validateEmail();
  });


function validateEmail() {
    var uemail = $('#YOURTEXTAREAHERE').val();
    alert(uemail);
    validatePassword();

}
```

Also I think this is wrong you should never write

```
if (validateEmail()) {
}
```

Because you list functions always, this means they are always there. Use string or objects like

```
var temp = {}
temp.useme = 'bla bla'
```

temp.useme can be used anywhere from the script also if it would be created somewhere inside.

Comment: Thanks. I did it. The control still does not reach inside validateEmail function. I have a dummy alert statement as the first statement inside validateEmail() and it does not print. Anything more you see suspicious in the code?

Comment: when you write new code debug everywhere. So first make alert('test1') at the beginning of the $('#loginBtn').click(function(){} to see if the click worked. If not you maybe didn´t use document ready. But this allround everything you do $(document).ready(function() {}  This means if the everything is loaded correctly then start javascript code. As example I create external js files and put the document ready function at the beginning and then I put everything inside. You cal also put your js codes inline. Both is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Currently no value is returned from `validateEmail()` function.

`return` a `Boolean`, that is `true` or `false`, or a value which will evaluate to `true` or `false` from `validateEmail()` function call for the `Boolean` to be evaluated within `if` condition at `signinVals()` function call.

Comment: Thanks. I did it. It still didn't work. :-( In fact, the issue is that it is not reaching this function. Alert is not displaying which is right after the first statement. I also tried alert(document.signinformid.usrname.value); and that did not work either as the first statement inside validateEmail()

Comment: @newstudent Can you describe "didn't work"? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve